# firewalld - change destination of outgoing http and https requests from local process

Tags: proxy, firewalld, rhel-7

I have a process that listens for incoming port 80 and 443 traffic and then sends it out to an extranet recipient. It's a proxy but I don't want to use that term because I need to send ITS outgoing requests through a company proxy. However, the app is not designed with a config option for proxy and it does not respect any system proxy settings.

I was experimenting with firewalld but could not change the destination IP of only the port 80 and 443 OUTGOING traffic. I think it ended up redirecting all INCOMING traffic coming on 80 and 443.

I can post some rules I have used but I'm hoping this is straightforward to firewalld veterans - I have only touched it a couple of times.

This is on RHEL 7, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to you to use NAT for this matter :

1 - Enable IP forwarding : `echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >>  /etc/sysctl.conf ; sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

2 - Start IPtables : `sudo systemctl start iptables`

3- Forward Incoming traffic on port 443 & 80 to your dest_ip:dest_port

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <dest_ip>:<dest_port>
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination <dest_ip>:<dest_port>
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d <dest_ip> --dport <dest_port> -j SNAT --to-source <source_ip>
```

4 - Check that the trules are correctly set : `sudo iptables -t nat -L -n`

5 - Test & then make your rules permanent :

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```